# Vertical text, centered in div

Tags: css

I'm stuck on making a text (single line) run vertically and remain centered in its container, left to right AND top to bottom.

[image]

How do I get it done with CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Use `transform` property to rotate your div Here is your css and `padding` for making vertical center align and `text-align` for making gorizontal center align. Crossbrowser solution:

```
div {
    margin: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
        -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
        -ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
        transform: scale(1) rotate(90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
}
p {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/YANxZ/

**UPD:** You can easily edit css3 properties (like `transform`) in this generator: http://css3generator.com/

Comment: this padding is just for eyeballing the center right? I don't see it act as a true auto center

Comment: yes, it is. But you know width and height of your div, so you can easily set it to actual value

Answer (score 0):

```
text-align:center;
line-height:1000px;
-moz-transform:rotate(-270deg); 
-moz-transform-origin: bottom left;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
-o-transform: rotate(-270deg);
-o-transform-origin:  bottom left;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
```

hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstofall postion your text the way you like, without trying to implement rotation.

Apply `transform: rotate(-90deg); along with vendor specifics on your div